# Simple Screen Recorder doesn't record anymore

Tags: screencast, desktop-recording

I was using it normally, but yesterday when I started to record, it didn't run.

It "starts", as if it was recording, but when I save the video, the file is 0 bytes. The video doesn't run.

Also, I saw that when I start recording,  the "time" stays on 0:00:00.

Can anyone help me?